# Docker Image Build Strange Behavior With Network Access

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to build an Ubuntu based docker image. I'm using Pop_OS as the host OS. My Docker versions are up to date.
My `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file contains:

```
{
        "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

Basic MVC for the Ubuntu Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get install build-essential
```

and issuing `docker build .` ends up with

```
0.210 E: Unable to locate package build-essential
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM ubuntu:20.04
   2 | >>> RUN apt-get install build-essential
   3 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install build-essential" did not complete successfully
```

removing the apt install line, and inspecting the /etc/resolv.conf in the container shows

```
root@0a3c00aaaae0:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Changing the Dockerfile to

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add curl
```

and running `docker build .` is successful
and inspecting the `/etc/resolv.conf` shows

```
$ docker exec -it <container> /bin/sh
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

but instead of having no access to the network, I'm able to ping google and interact as expected.

Does anyone have any clues as to what is causing this?

Comment: Do you need to run `apt-get update` before trying to install things?  You usually need include this in the same `RUN` line as `apt-get install` for layer-caching reasons.

Comment: It's been a bit since I've had to make a ubuntu based image. I'm shocked that this was the solution! If you want to make this an answer I'll mark it as accepted.